# Meaning of these options: hadn't packed/ weren't packing

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

Context: on an English learning book I have been instructed to underline the "correct" option. The sentence is the following:

When we were at sea, we realized we *hadn't packed*/*weren't packing* the first-aid kit.

As for me, both options are right, because the rest of the sentence(context) doesn't make it clear which option is the appropriate to make this sentence grammatically correct.

Comment: "Packing", when it doesn't refer to the time when the baggage is being packed, refers to carrying a weapon.  Generally, by the time you've departed you should have finished packing.

Comment: hummm... so, *weren't* doesn't provide a context of tense in this case? Therefore *packing* should bee taken as carrying a weapon?

Comment: @Hot Licks  One gangster talking to another: "We might be packing, but we haven't packed our first-aid kit."  The Mob sense is originally US, and still is, predominantly, to my ear. "carrying" possibly, in Britspeak. [_Green's Dictionary of Slang_](https://greensdictofslang.com/) would no doubt elucidate.

Comment: On a backpacking trip on might ask, “Hey, who’s packing the first-aid kit?”.  But lots of times a multiple choice question seeks the ***best*** answer among several viable answers.  “***hadn’t packed*** is clearly the best of the two because one doesn’t need to contrive a situation to make it fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hadn't packed/weren't packing** the first aid kit

The right choice is "hadn't packed", because packing for the trip is completed in the past.

The second option is wrong because it tries to use "weren't packing" to mean "weren't carrying", meaning "didn't have the first aid kit with us."

There's a U.S. slang use of "packing", short for "packing heat", which means carrying a concealed weapon.  See [packing heat](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/what-does-packing-heat-mean) for the details.

You can look up "pack" in its conventional meaning on-line, e.g., in MW.

Comment: According to [GDoS](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/a2fuh5i#qqvijia), **_pack_** (carry a weapon) is the earliest -- 1863. **_heat_** (for a pistol) first appears in 1929. **_pack heat_** is the last to appear -- 1939.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry it took me more than 3 years to mark it.